# PHP Print web page with iframe and some other content with pdf on one page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I want to print a web page which has some text and 2 iframes loading single page PDF files. When I try to print it on a single sheet but it only shows the text and not the iframes.
This is the code I used

> html/php

```
<iframe class="iframe_budget" scrolling="no" src="ProjectFiles/<?php echo $project_budget_url; ?>" width="100px" height="100px"></iframe>
```

> .css

```
.iframe_budget { width: 300px; height: 390px;background: #fff;border: none; }
    .iframe_budget {
            -ms-zoom: 1;
            -moz-transform: scale(1);
            -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
            -o-transform: scale(1);
            -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
```

This is the web page I want to print
[image]

and this is the print preview I get
[image]

Is it possible to shrink the iframe to fit it into the page when printing??

Comment: Can you add a link to the original page?

Comment: its on localhost. I can upload the entire php/html page if necessary

Comment: I'm not sure you will be able to do this consistently: you will have folks using different browser/plugin combinations that may or may not allow this to happen. Is there any way to render the data inside the original page somehow?